# Can't populate JAXB pojo classes to make XML file using factory methods

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, factory

I cannot figure out how to populate (set) my factory generated POJO's using generated java classes by marshalling. I generated XML output of what I want, generated the .xsd schema from this xml(XMLSPY), and using Eclipse 2019-06 and jre1.8.0_191 generated the POJO's.  Here is a representation of my schema:

```
 //discussion
        //forum
              //properties
                   //display_order
                   //is_hidden
                   // requires_approval
                   //is_locked
                   //must_post_to_participate
                   //show_description_in_topics
              //content
                   //title
              //topics
                   //topic
                        //properties
                            //allow_anon
                            //display_order
                            //is_hidden
                            //requires_approval
                            //must_post_to_participate
                            //is_locked
                            //score_out_of
                            //is_auto_score
                            //include_nonscored_values
                            //rating_type_id
                        //content
                             //<title>
                             //<description>


 Here is the marshalling:
   try {
          JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Discussion.class);
          Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE); // To format XML

        //Print XML String to Console
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(discussion, System.out);

     } catch (JAXBException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
```

Multiple CONTENT and PROPERTIES constructs are not helpful. The generated classes warned about this and refused to provide bland setters:

```
 You are getting this "catch-all" property because of the following reason: 
 * The field name "MustPostToParticipate" is used by two different parts of a schema. See: 
 * line 108 of file:discussion.xsd
 * line 104 of file:discussion.xsd
 * <p>
 * To get rid of this property, apply a property customization to one 
 * of both of the following declarations to change their names: 
 * Gets the value of the content property.
 * 
 * <p>
 * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
 * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
 * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
 * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the content property.
 * 
 * <p>
 * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
 * <pre>
 *    getContent().add(newItem);
 * </pre>
```

(I did read how to modify the .xsd to take care of this, not sure I have to.)

First I tried a kind of inverse-order methology, I create empty objects in the 
proper hierarchy order, then try to populate the parent objects by adding
in the children -

```
  ObjectFactory discObjFctry = new ObjectFactory();
    Discussion discussion = discObjFctry.createDiscussion();
         Forum forum = discObjFctry.createForum();

               //major structure - 3 siblings
               Properties properties = discObjFctry.createProperties();
               Content content = discObjFctry.createContent();    
               Topics topics = discObjFctry.createTopics();
```

Now I try to populate the siblings, when that's done I thought I could do this - add the
populated POJO's to their parent object:

```
 // last steps 
               forum.setId((byte) 1);  //attribute
               forum.setResourceCode("Resource Code Dude");  //attribute
               forum.setProperties(properties); // add sibling 1 object
               forum.setContent(content);   // add sibling 2 object
               forum.setTopics(topics);  // add sibling 3 object
               discussion.setForum(forum);  // root level
```

Keeping in mind I'm searching around for what works, eventually I had to resort to letting
Eclipse suggest some of the nomenclature

```
                  // 1st grouping of elements - set Properties
       ERR LINE  forum.properties.content.set(0, discObjFctry.createAllowAnon("False"));
                 forum.properties.content.set(1, discObjFctry.createDisplayOrder((byte) 1));
                 forum.properties.content.set(2, discObjFctry.createIsHidden("False"));
                 forum.properties.content.set(3, discObjFctry.createRequiresApproval("False"));
                 forum.properties.content.set(4, discObjFctry.createIsLocked("False"));
                 forum.properties.content.set(5, discObjFctry.createMustPostToParticipate("False"));
                 forum.properties.content.set(6, 
   discObjFctry.createShowDescriptionInTopics("False"));

                 // 2nd grouping of elements - set Content
                 forum.content.setTitle("This is the content title"); 
                 forum.content.setDescription("This is the content itself - description field");

                 // 3rd grouping of elements - set Topics.Topic.Properties and Topics.Topic.Content 
                 Topic topic = discObjFctry.createTopic(); // topic has properties & content

                 //first branch
                 forum.topics.topic.properties.content.set(0, 
      discObjFctry.createAllowAnon("False"));
                 forum.topics.topic.properties.content.set(0, discObjFctry.createDisplayOrder((byte) 
 1));
                 forum.topics.topic.properties.content.set(0, discObjFctry.createIsHidden("False"));
                 forum.topics.topic.properties.content.set(0, 
 discObjFctry.createRequiresApproval("False"));
                 forum.topics.topic.properties.content.set(0, 
 discObjFctry.createMustPostToParticipate("False"));
                 forum.topics.topic.properties.content.set(0, discObjFctry.createIsLocked("False"));
                 forum.topics.topic.properties.content.set(0, discObjFctry.createScoreOutOf((byte) 
 0));
                 forum.topics.topic.properties.content.set(0, 
 discObjFctry.createIsAutoScore("False"));
                 forum.topics.topic.properties.content.set(0, 
 discObjFctry.createIncludeNonscoredValues("False"));
                 forum.topics.topic.properties.content.set(0, discObjFctry.createRatingTypeId((byte) 
 0));

                 // other branch
                 forum.topics.topic.content.setDescription("Topics Topic Content Description");
                 forum.topics.topic.content.setTitle("Topics Topic Content Title");
```

I also tried this by taking off the forum and forum.topics respectively and having the numbers
run sequentially
The error (ERR LINE) above is java.lang.NullPointerException

I can't get any data into the POJO's. I've played around with constructs like:

```
 JAXBElement<Properties> aJAXBedPojo = new JAXBElement<Properties>(new QName("allow_anon"), 
 Properties.class, properties);
```

and

```
    properties.content.add(0, discObjFctry.createAllowAnon("False"));
```

and 
       Properties propertiesObj = new Properties("False", (byte) 1, "False", "False", "False", "False", 
      "False");

This partially works

```
  JAXBElement<String> allow_anon = discussionObjectFactory.createAllowAnon("False");
  System.out.println("tom=" + allow_anon.getValue());
    forum.properties.getContent().add(allow_anon);  ERR LAST LINE: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I also tried (for the first Properties)

```
 Properties propertiesObj = new Properties("False", (byte) 1, "False", "False", "False", "False", 
 "False");
```

Maybe I've got the right elements here (no XML pun intended) but I can't make it work. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Read this: [Customizing JAXB Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/custom.html). --- *"Why Customize? [...] To resolve name collisions [...]"* --- You need that because your XSD likely *(not sure, you didn't show it)* has elements of the same name.

Comment: You could also modify the XSD to name the element types better, so there would be no need for a binding file. Difficult to make suggestions, when we can't see a small example of your XSD.